# If $f$ maps any measurable set to a measurable set, then is $f$ a measurable map?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $(X,\sigma)$ and $(Y,\nu)$ are measurable space and $f:\ X\longrightarrow Y$ is a map that takes each measurable set of $\sigma$ to a measurable set of $\nu$, then is $f$ needed to be measurable, i.e preimage of measurable set in $Y$ is a measurable set in $X$ ?

In general topology, an open map - a map $f:\ X\longrightarrow Y$ that turns every open set in $X$ to an open set in $Y$, is not needed to be continuous. However, the sigma-algebra in general is a larger than the topology, so is there any chance that a map that brings measurable sets to measurables sets is a measurable map ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Here is a simple counter-example.

Let $X=Y=[0,1]$. Let $\sigma =\{\emptyset, [0,1]\}$ and $\nu=\mathcal{P}([0,1])$. It is easy to see that $\sigma$ and $\nu$ are $\sigma$-algebra. Let $f:\ X \rightarrow Y$ be the map defined as $f(x) =x$, for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Clearly, $f$ takes each measurable set of $\sigma$ to a measurable set of $\nu$. However $f$ is not measurable, since, for instance, $\{0\} \in \nu$, but $f^{-1}(\{0\})= \{0\} \notin \sigma$.

**Remark**: In fact, in the counter-example $[0,1]$ can be replaced by any set having two or more elements.

Comment: I see. So, is there any results relate to the maps that take measurable sets to measurable sets, that is similar to the results relate to open maps in topology ?

Comment: @PermQi ,  There is not a perfect parallel, but there are some similar results, for instance:  if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a bijection and $f$ takes measurable sets to measurable sets, then $f^{-1}$ is measurable. 
Which "results related to open maps in topology" do you mean?